# twitter authentication API issue

Tags: java, ssl, twitter, oauth

In the twitter API for `auth` before redirection i get **http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=345werfgsdfgsdfg** instead of **https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=345werfgsdfgsdfg** and the response **SSL is required**

But I configured SSL yet still Twitter is redirecting to http, not https.

Am I doing any mistakes?

Please help me out.

Comment: Are you sending requests to the http or the https address? Can you just hit the https address directly and avoid the redirection all together?

Comment: thanks but i am using https address only, if i am hitng with https then login page is coming

Comment: Which library are you using? Have you updated it to the latest version?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
   </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

When i changed my twitter4j version **3.0.3 to 3.0.6** it worked for me 
thanks